# UWP start EXE with FullTrustesdLauncher on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-iot-core-10

I created a UWP-application which starts an external application over its EXE-File using the FullTrustedLauncher. 
It works fine when I start the UWP-App on the computer (local) but the problem occurs when I start the UWP-app on a Raspberry Pi. 
The EXE-File can't be run with following Error: "Class not referenced"
By the way the EXE-File I want to run is an ASP.NET Core application.

Am I missing some .dll-files or what should I do to start an EXE on a Raspberry Pi? Are there better alternatives than using the FullTrustedLauncher for UWP-applications?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ProcessLauncher API in Windows IOT. Here is a sample and documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/master/Samples/ExternalProcessLauncher/CS/README.md

Answer (score 0):

FullTrustProcessLauncher is a Desktop Extensions SDK API, as called out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher). It is only supported (and present) on the desktop device family, not on iot or any other SKU of Windows.

Comment: Is there an alternative how to solve this problem without using FullTrustedProcessLauncher?
Isn't there a way to run a EXE over a UWP-app on Windows IoT / Raspberry PI?